# How to stop tomcat 7 with maven in eclipse

Tags: maven, tomcat, jakarta-ee, maven-plugin, maven-tomcat-plugin

When I run my maven web project in eclipse. I go to `pom.xml`, right click on the file and
 1. Maven Clean
 2. Build Resources
 3. Maven Build ..

Then I type `tomcat7:run` (for tomcat 7) for tomcat 6 , `tomcat:run` in the tomcat goals field in eclipse . It just starts. But I want to know how
1. To stop it
2. Rebuild the source and redeploy

in elipse or any other quick easy step. Isn't there any way to do all stuff to start the tomcat instead of repeating fore said steps(maven clean.. building resource.. again type tomcat7:run ... ) in eclipse.

Comment: **Note:** The OP does *not* ask for the /stop-Manager-Command of Tomcat7 for individual webapplications. The Stop-Function for individual deployed webapplications of Tomcat7 is not implemented in the Maven-Plugin yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try right click on pom.xml > Run As > Maven Build...
Define here in the Goals section all your commands, something like: clean install tomcat7:run

My recommendation is to check skip tests for faster start up time, you can add extra paramenters like -Denvironment=qa if needed or VM arguments (from the JRE tab) like -Xmx2048m -Xms256m

Also, put a name to the configuration since you will be able to Run it again with a simple click or you could copy the .launch file eclipse generates into your application and commit it.

To stop the server just click the red square from the console view.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The red square from the console does not stop the server, but terminates it. This way any context listeners for shutdown will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me:

mvn tomcat7:shutdown

http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/tomcat7-maven-plugin/shutdown-mojo.html

Comment: Could you give an example how it looks like after reconfigure it in pom?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JRebel to hot-deploy your changes, no need to stop/start the app.
In IntelliJ use Ctrl+Shift+F9 to recompile and hot-deploty current changes.
Installing JRebel takes 5 minutes, and running app under JRebel is relally easy:

```
mvn <your usual parameteres here> -Djrebel.
```

If you search around, you can get JRebel for free.

Also, nothing stops you from running your maven application in a command line. Then stopping your app is as easy as hitting Ctrl+C.

You can also try maven tomcat shutdown plugin: http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/shutdown-mojo.html.

Answer (score -1):

I use [JBoss Tools](http://tools.jboss.org/) for managing Containers from Eclipse.

Comment: would you explain more please ?

Comment: There is a plugin to Eclipse called JBoss Tools, it will allow you to start and stop the servers (Tomcat in your case) from inside Eclipse. It will also allow you to deploy your Web Application to that server, also from inside Eclipse. Follow the "JBoss Tools" link in my post to read more about the plugin.

Answer (score -1):

Just close the window for eclipse if the red square from the console view is not available.