# How to stop maven tomcat

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat

I am very new to Maven builds. I have created a maven project and running it using maven build. It is running fine using tomcat7:run as goal but then I am finding it hard to stop the server. I am getting following error when I try to run again.

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind <null>:8080
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: have you tired to run shutdown.bat on tomcat server?

Comment: This is embedded tomcat server

Comment: suppose you refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25592039/how-to-stop-tomcat-7-with-maven-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the process is still running, you should be able to see it in your console. If you see a stop button (like *1*), just press it and that should stop the tomcat server.

If you happen to have had more than one service running, then the button in *2* should be activated. That will show all the running and stopped services you have. Select the one for your Tomcat and then press the stop button.

[image]

Comment: I cant' believe it was that simple. I tried so many things but here you go there were more than two instances running. Thank you

Comment: If you want to close one or more consoles, there are two buttons just right of the the stop. The first one (one 'X') closes the current window. The second one (two 'X's) closes all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mvn tomcat7:shutdown` command to stop.

> Shuts down all possibly started embedded tomcat servers. This will be automatically down through a shutdown hook or you may call this Mojo to shut them down explictly.

Here is the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html).